# Problem in installing the ADT plugin

Tags: android, eclipse, installation, adt

I am very new to Android development. I am trying to install the working environment in Windows Vista . I installed java EE with jdk 6.0, Android SDK and the eclipse. When I try to install the ADT plugin in the software updates, I am not finding any available software list. I am confused where I went wrong. Did anybody face this kind of problem.

Regards,
Viji

Answer (score 0):

Is your internet connection available?

Or the update server down?

Did you add Add-on site? https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository.xml

There are too many possibilities...

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. I tried  adding this site https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/ and install it. But after adding this site I am not getting the install button enabled.

Answer (score 0):

The installation for ADT Plugin for Eclipse are already given at: http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html ,

1. Start Eclipse, then select Help > Install New Software.
2. In the Available Software dialog, click Add....
3. In the Add Site dialog that appears, enter a name for the remote site (for example, "Android Plugin") in the "Name" field.

   In the "Location" field, enter this URL:

   https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/

   Note: If you have trouble acquiring the plugin, you can try using "http" in the URL, instead of "https" (https is preferred for security reasons).

   Click OK.
4. Back in the Available Software view, you should now see "Developer Tools" added to the list. Select the checkbox next to Developer Tools, which will automatically select the nested tools Android DDMS and Android Development Tools. Click Next.
5. In the resulting Install Details dialog, the Android DDMS and Android Development Tools features are listed. Click Next to read and accept the license agreement and install any dependencies, then click Finish.
6. Restart Eclipse.

Pls refer this, and i think as soon as you entered according to the 3rd Field, you will face the following dialog image:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Bit of an extended answer as further info for those coming in through google.

If you genuinely have this issue then neither of these answers will help.  The top one is a good (paste of official) guide.  However theres some libraries missing from ADT or something...regardless of the actual reasons this doesnt work out-of-the-box for everyone.

I see faliure to find software lists also when using eclipse's add software through both the http and https protocols.  Bear in mind however that eclipse calculates dependencies first and this can take some time

Its worth checking your network, make sure any proxy is correctly configured through eclipse. (iirc its window->preferences->General->Network Connections)

If all else fails (and it did for me) then you can manually download the ADT plugin as a .zip from the eclipse site.  You then install it very similarly to the online method.  Instead of entering an http or https path you should instead click 'Archive' and browse to the appropriate zip.  This will fill the software box with the relevant modules and allow install.  You can then return to step 4 in Paresh's instructions